# WPF custom window with AllowsTransparency="False"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How i can create window without borders, but reszable and window property AllowsTransparency must be set to false, because i am using winforms control that does not allow this. Maybe there are already some lib for custom windows (but they must have AllowsTransparency setted to false)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this would help you.

[WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library)

Comment: Hmm looks great. Investigate if there are no some underwater rocks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its setting `WindowsStyle="None"` that removes the borders.

If you are drawing a transparent window then you have to set `WindowStyle="None"` whenever you set `AllowsTransparency="True"`, but its isn't true the other way round.

Comment: When WindowStyle is none, you can't resize the window.

Comment: yes i see, but the problem that i am using resithe with grip property, so it is returning borders. Maybe there are some smart implementation of sizing without lags and delays?